# How to keep content in position when zooming in and out on your browser

Tags: html, css

I have a div where I inputted a picture and I "Position: absolute" another div that when clicked will bring you down to the bottom of the page. But when you zoom out, it stays in place but, when you zoom out it moves down and out of the picture div. I am asking, how do i keep my content centered and in position when zooming in and out of your browser. I searched all over stack and other websites but can't find a solution.

HTML

```css
#pic-div {
 width: 100%;
 height: 700px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#pic-button {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
#down-button {
 max-width: 200px;
 max-height: 200px;
 background-color: black;
 border-style: none;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Coiny', cursive;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 500px;
}
#down-button:hover {
 background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="pic-div">
<div id="welcome-pic"> <img id="pic-welcome" src="luxpics/logobar.jpg">
  <div id="pic-button">
    <button id="down-button">LET'S START</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#down-button {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  border-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Coiny', cursive;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 25px;
  //margin-top: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using **position: fixed** instead of using absolute?

Comment: When i give it a fixed position, it makes it move everywhere i scroll.

Comment: Add these together -   position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;