# How can I make the login container fixed?

Tags: html, css

Here is the link to the example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRSGV.jpg.

And the css for it:

```
.login-container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("../../storage/assets/nave.jpeg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  .login-form {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 520px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 35px 35px 15px 35px;
    margin: 305px auto;
    background-color:white;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  }
```

When I am trying to zoom in, the image remain fixed, but the form keep going down is that the intended behavior?

Comment: Please post your html and relevant css for the same. It would be difficult to say without seeing your code

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by zooming in? literally displaying the page not at 100% but eg 150% ?

Comment: yeah that's what i meant by that

Comment: Should i try to put in a jsFiddle? But i used element-ui and i don't know if it will work

Comment: according to this answer it could have to do with your margin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623920/how-to-keep-content-in-position-when-zooming-in-and-out-on-your-browser

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try right now